# Using Linq IQueryable, set which field to filter on depending on another field in the same table

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I have a car table with three fields.
I need to filter on one of two fields depending on the value of the third field.
If the vehicle is marked as "Special", then filter on the SpecialPrice field otherwise filter on the "NormalPrice" field.
What I need help with is how to write the Linq query to decide which field to filter on depending on the Special boolean field value.

Example Table: Car

`Special: bool`

`SpecialPrice: int`

`NormalPrice: int`

```
IQueryable<Car> query = _context.Car;

if (Special)
 query = query.Where(x => x.SpecialPrice <= 100);
else
 query = query.Where(x => x.NormalPrice <= 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
query = query.Where(x => x.Special == true ? x.SpecialPrice <= 100 : x.NormalPrice <= 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've got your requirement clear, the query will be straightforward.

**Requirement**: So you have a price value, and you want only Cars that have:

```
car.Special AND car.SpecialPrice == price
OR
not car.Special AND car.NormalPrice == price
```

The query:

```
decimal price = 100;
var result = dbContext.Cars.Where(car =>

    (car.Special && car.SpecialPrice == price)
 || (!car.Special && car.NormalPrice == price));
```

Simple comme bonjour!